# How to send json data with file in same response using express,node,mongodb?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I uploaded files using multer and gridfs storage and everything is working fine. After uploading file I saved my userdetails with filepath in user collection.

Now I want to retrieve userdata from user collection.

In the response, I need to send image and user details.

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
    User.findById('58fdea1793e794256c2e0820', function (err, user) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!user) { return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); }

    //console.log(user);
         var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                filename: user.filepath,
                root: "ctFiles"
            });
            /** set the proper content type */
            res.set('Content-Type', user.filepath.contentType)


           //return readstream.pipe(res);
            return res.json(user);

  });
```

For this user I am getting response like this

```
 { 
   _id: 58fdea1793e794256c2e0820,
   name: 'asdfs',
   email:'asdf@gmail.com'
   filepath: 'file-1493035543005.jpg',
   __v: 0 
 }
```

If I use 'return readstream.pipe(res);' image got displayed 
but I want to send image as well as name and email

Help me out.

Comment: Basically, you want send the `image` blob instead of your current `filepath` right?

Comment: i want to send image with name and email and image should display on andriod and angular

Comment: Does your `/user` endpoint returns the image object?

Comment: if i use return readstream.pipe(res);  and call user api image getting displayed in browser

Comment: Can you try using `res.attachment(user.filepath);` before you use `return readstream.pipe(res);` ?

Comment: file got downloded

Comment: What happens when you use `res.send(user);` in place of `res.attachment...` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142574/discussion-between-its-me-and-david-r).

Comment: i m getting error events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: invalid media type