# How to display image in angular(image uploded in server side uploads folder and angularjs is working in different server)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, multer

I uploaded image using multer,node.js,mongodb.

I uploaded the image in upload folder and I stored the path in MongoDB.

this is my folder structure

[image]

server is running

```
http://localhost:3000/images/590051dcc90cf702e452b9c1
```

based on document id I am retriving document

```
// To get the single image/File using id from the MongoDB
app.get('/images/:id', function(req, res) {

//calling the function from index.js class using routes object..
routes.getImageById(req.params.id, function(err, genres) {
if (err) {
throw err;
}
//res.download(genres.path);
res.send(genres)
});
});
```

I got response like this

```
{"_id":"590051dcc90cf702e452b9c1","path":"uploads\login.jpg","name":"asdf","email":"asdf@gmail.com","originalname":"login.jpg","__v":0}
```

I am sending the above response to angular and andriod application.

now I want to display this image in angular .

angular server is working in diffrent server node server is working in different server

i put like this

```
</head><body>
<body ng-controller="RegisterCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-init="signin()">
 <img ng-src="{{response.path}}"/>
   {{response}}
    </div>
</body>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js'></script>
<script>var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

$scope.signin = function()

{

$http.get('http://localhost:3000/images/590051dcc90cf702e452b9c1').success(function(data, response)
{
$scope.response  = data;
console.log(data);
}); 

}
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

i am getting error

```
file:///C:/Users/mohan/Desktop/uploads/login.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

bcoz file is located in server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Node JS server convert the get api method to fetch the image path from Mongo Db and return the byte array of the image.

```
// To get the single image/File using id from the MongoDB
app.get('/images/:id', function(req, res) {

        //calling the function from index.js class using routes object..
        routes.getImageById(req.params.id, function(err, genres) {
             if (err) {
                 throw err;
             }
             //res.download(genres.path);
             var fs = require('fs');
             // read binary data
             var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(genres.path);
             // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
             //res.send(new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64'));
             genres.path = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');

             res.send(genres)
           });
});
```

Bind this byte array to your  tag.

```
  <img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,' + response.data.path}}">
```

Comment: image displayed now but i did not get "name":"asdf" and "email":"asdf@gmail.com"

Comment: just the matter of assigning the image base64 string to your path property of genres object. I have updated my answer. Accept the answer if that solves your problem.

Comment: if i add this code not working .but if i give <img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,' + response}}"> then image is displaying but i am not getting name and email

Comment: can we have quick chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143454/discussion-between-kalyan-and-its-me).

Comment: if i want to retrive all the images from collection ?

Comment: Bring it as an array of image bytes

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is much helpful for me :).

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the path to image using `ng-src`

Assume this is the response json

```
$scope.response = {"_id":"590051dcc90cf702e452b9c1","path":"uploads\login.jpg","name":"asdf","email":"asdf@gmail.com","originalname":"login.jpg","__v":0}
```

in the image tag.

```
<img ng-src"{{response.path}}">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603303/how-to-send-json-data-with-file-in-same-response-using-express-node-mongodb

Comment: I have a similar thing to this except I'm using angular 5, I have an array of images so I'm using a for loop to go through them and when I do `img src = {{product.path}}` it adds localhost:4200 ( the angular app) but instead I want to display localhost:3000 which is the server side (nodejs) any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img ng-src="{{response.path}}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm whether the image is available in the url, 'http://localhost:3000/uploads/login.jpg'?

If not, the image path is not correct. Please check whether it is uploaded into the folder correctly.

Comment: image available in uploads folder but when i do http://localhost:3000/uploads/login.jpg   . i got message Cannot GET /uploads/login.jpg

Comment: That means this image is not accessible. Please check whether there are any permission settings.

Comment: how can i check that ?

Comment: What is the response status you are getting? 404 or 401?